# Can't access Object property with ngModel in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I am new to Angular, and I try to build an app that handles a webshop with clients and products. in the app.component.html file I have a select function to let the user select products from a dropdown list:

```html
  <select  name="select_product" [(ngModel)]="selectedProduct">
    <option default>Choose a product!</option>
    <option *ngFor="let product of products">{{product?.name}}, {{product?.id}}</option>
  </select>
```

I declared the selectedProduct variable in the Component:

```
public selectedProduct: Product;
```

When the user picks an item from the dropdown list, I can access the resulting object, and display it in html with this reference:

```
{{selectedProduct}}
```

But when I try to access properties of this selectedProduct, it won't display, and all the fields disappear from the options.

```
{{selectedProduct.id}}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the **[value]** attribute in the `<option>` tag.

```
  <select name="select_product" [(ngModel)]="selectedProduct">
    <option default [value]="null">Choose a product!</option>
    <option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product">{{product.name}}, {{product.id}}</option>
  </select>
```

UPD:

```
[value]="..." only supports string values
[ngValue]="..." supports any type
```

Updated example:

```
  <select name="select_product" [(ngModel)]="selectedProduct">
    <option default [ngValue]="null">Choose a product!</option>
    <option *ngFor="let product of products" [ngValue]="product">{{product.name}}, {{product.id}}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Thank you, I just tried your proposal, but it did not help. Still no way to access the 'name' attribute of selectedProduct. I can access the product in the *ngFor-loop, and its various attributes, but but not the selectedProduct attributes (which is also a product-object).

Comment: @Somo I've updated example

Comment: Thank you, this way it works just fine. Your help is much appreciated!